# Response of a request is undefined when used with Export

Tags: javascript, node.js

In one file, I have the following functions to call an external API and get some data

```
function RequestCallback(error, response, body) {
  if(error) console.log(error);

  var new_body = *do something with the body*
  console.log(new_body);
  return new_body
}

var apiCall = function apiCall(payload, authObj, guest) {
    var reqBody = *build the body here*

    return request({
      url: 'the api url',
      method: 'POST',
      encoding: null,
      headers: {
        //pass some headers
      },
      body: reqBody,
    }, RequestCallback);
}

module.exports = {
  apiCall: apiCall
};
```

Then in another file, I call it like this:

```
const apiService = require("./services.js");
var res = apiService.apiCall(payload, authObj, guest);
console.log(res);
```

The first `console.log` prints the response correctly. The second `console.log` prints `undefined`. I have the feeling, it is about calling asynchronously the function, but I am clueless how to fix this without rewriting the whole part.

Answer (score 0):

You're close... The issue you're having is that you only have access to your data inside of your `RequestCallback` (because the data will be returned asynchronously after your request is complete).

So a common pattern you'll see in javascript is passing an anonymous function, or [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), as a function argument that receives the data when it becomes available. This gives the caller the control to do whatever they want with the asynchronously returned data.

Consider modifying your `apiCall` function to take in a `callback` parameter so that you can pass in a function/closure that will do something with the response once its returned.

**services.js**

```js
// note the new function signature takes in a `callback` parameter
var apiCall = function apiCall(payload, authObj, guest, callback) {
  var reqBody = *build the body here*

  return request(
    {
      url: "the api url",
      method: "POST",
      encoding: null,
      headers: {
        //pass some headers
      },
      body: reqBody,
    },
    callback  // the callback is passed here and will get called when the data is ready
  );
};

module.exports = {
  apiCall: apiCall,
};
```

Now in your entry point file, I'll assume it is **index.js**:

```js
const apiService = require("./services.js");
var res = apiService.apiCall(payload, authObj, guest, function(error, response, body) {
    if(error) console.log(error);

    var new_body = *do something with the body*
    console.log(new_body);
});
```

Now whatever you want to do with your data will need to happen inside of that callback.

Comment: Unfortunately, the callback requires to have some generic code that needs to be repeated everywhere if I do it like that. That's why I wanted to have a generic callback and then get the result, so based on the place I call the `apiService.apiCall(payload, authObj, guest);` I can then do the specific part only

Comment: @Tasos do you mind sharing what http library you're using?

Comment: Sure, it's this one `"request": "^2.88.2",`